# onChange not working in my onLoad function to display correct answers

Tags: javascript, html

I made a html document calculating the surface area and volume of anything that is entered into the input boxes in my html document of Height, Width, and Length. Instead of using a button to run the functions and make the answers appear in the input boxes designated as Surface Area and Volume for the answers I wanted to use a onload and make it so whenever each input box is changed both functions run. I am fairly new to Javascript and the method I was tried below just leaves the screen blank, What exactly is causing the answers to not display in the text boxes? How might I solve this?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Surface Area &amp; Volume</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
<script>
"use strict";


    var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    var amountVolume = 0;

    var length = $("length");
    var width = $("widthData");
    var height = $("heightData");
    var surfaceArea;
    var surfaceAreaArray = [];

    function output() {

     function calculateVolume(length, width, height) {
        amountVolume = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * parseFloat(height);
        var volumeRound = amountVolume.toFixed(2);
        $('volume').value = volumeRound;
    }

    function calculateSurfaceArea(length, width, height) {
        surfaceAreaArray[0] = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * 2;
        surfaceAreaArray[1] = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(height) * 2;
        surfaceAreaArray[2] = parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(width) * 2;
        surfaceArea = surfaceAreaArray[0] + surfaceAreaArray[1] + surfaceAreaArray[2];
        var areaRound = surfaceArea.toFixed(1);
        $('area').value = areaRound;
    }

    }
window.onload = function() {

    $("length").onchange = output; 

    $("widthData").onchange = output;

    $("heightData").onchange = output;
}



</script>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <form>
    <h1>Surface Area & Volume</h1>

    <p>Length:

    <input type="text" id="length" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Width:

        <input type="text" id="widthData" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p>Height:

        <input type="text" id="heightData" value="0"/>

    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="change">Surface Area:

        <input type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class="volume">Volume:

        <input type="text" id="volume" disabled="disabled" />
    </p>
    <br />
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `output` isn't actually calling `calculateVolume` or `calculateSurfaceArea`. It's just defining them. So every time you change your input, you're just redefining some functions and not actually running anything.

Secondly, you need to pass the values of the inputs into those functions. `var length = $("length");` gets the whole element. It should become `var length = $("length").value;` to get the actual numerical values.

Finally, you may want to call `output()` once in `onload` to start the surface area and volume fields off at 0.

This code should work:

```
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

function calculateVolume(length, width, height) {
  var amountVolume = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * parseFloat(height);
  var volumeRound = amountVolume.toFixed(2);
  $('volume').value = volumeRound;
}

function calculateSurfaceArea(length, width, height) {
  var surfaceAreaArray = [];
  surfaceAreaArray[0] = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(width) * 2;
  surfaceAreaArray[1] = parseFloat(length) * parseFloat(height) * 2;
  surfaceAreaArray[2] = parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(width) * 2;
  var surfaceArea = surfaceAreaArray[0] + surfaceAreaArray[1] + surfaceAreaArray[2];
  var areaRound = surfaceArea.toFixed(1);
  $('area').value = areaRound;
}

function output() {
  var length = $("length").value;
  var width = $("widthData").value;
  var height = $("heightData").value;

  calculateVolume(length, width, height)
  calculateSurfaceArea(length, width, height)

}
window.onload = function() {

  $("length").onchange = output;

  $("widthData").onchange = output;

  $("heightData").onchange = output;

  output();
}
```

You say you're new to JavaScript. You should go through the code above to make sure you understand why it works. Here's a nice introduction to functions which you may find useful: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html